# Xcode - Remote repo could not be accessed while adding swift package

Tags: ios, xcode, github, swift-package-manager

Hello I am using Xcode Version 14.1 (14B47b) and macOS 13.4.1 (22F82).
i am trying to install the SPM but i am facing below issue.

[SCREENSHOT of Xcode error SPM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57lAv.png)

Remote repo could not be accessed while adding swift package.

I have generated ssh key and config file managed too.

I have followed this document - https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Still issue exist and also i have tried by restarting xcode and Cloning repo again. Cleared derived data. Added github account again from setting.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you clone it in Terminal?

Comment: Hi @Larme, I am using github desktop to do clone commit push pull